# QList of structs in cpp and access the struct members in qml

Tags: c++, qt, listview, struct, qml

I am facing a same problem as that of fellow user,given is the link for the query similar to mine-

[Qt QML C++ QList of structs as custom ListView model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980900/qt-qml-c-qlist-of-structs-as-custom-listview-model)

but i want to stick with struct instead of class with QProperty having the members as that of struct and access these struct members in my qml. How can i do this?

Comment: You'll most likely have to wrap your structs in a QObject. Why not use a class directly?

Comment: I'd wrap the whole array if structs into a `QAbstractListModel`. It's a bit more work however.

Comment: The answer is already accepted in the link. "`QML` cannot access low-level struct types. "

Comment: `class` or `struct` doesn't really make a difference in C++ other than default access modifier.

Can you provide some information on what you want to do with your data? How do you want to use the objects and or their data in QML?